# pandarallel widgets don't work on Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pandarallel

Pandarallel supports nice progress widgets. However, I can't get them to appear when using Google Colab. I get output like this instead:

[image]

This chunk of code, which is supposed to enable the widgets, runs successfully in my notebook (before I use any parallel calls):

```
%pip install pandas librosa pandarallel jupyterlab jupyter_contrib_nbextensions jupyter-client -U
!jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
!jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager  --no-build
```

What am I missing?

Update: when I connect Google Colab to a local Jupyter instance, I see the proper widgets. It's only a problem when trying to run on the Google Jupyter instance.

Comment: is the notebook trusted? I had issues with running widgets on Google Colab where the notebook was not trusted, and all html elements, including widgets, would fail to load properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`is_notebook_lab`](https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel/blob/2353a97279a21375b33b9097039bee8d81936398/pandarallel/utils/progress_bars.py#L10) check is too narrow, you can overwrite it and force to be true:

```py
from pandarallel.utils import progress_bars

progress_bars.is_notebook_lab = lambda : True
```

FWIW for the installation you should only have to do `%pip install pandarallel`- the extension installation steps above should not be needed.

Comment: Fixed in Pandarallel v1.5.7.
Please not that the free version of Google Colab offers only one (hyperthreaded) core.
Pandarallel won't speed your computation up using it.